# Why do I only get integer values for canvas pixel RGB values, and why is it the same for 'stackblur'ed images?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to detect subtle changes in the red channel of a webcam video.

Using GetUserMedia to get the webcam images, then applying them to a canvas element, I can only get integer values for the RGB of pixels (using getImageData to find specific pixel values).

I've tried to interpolate higher precision by using a gaussian blur through [stackblur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) but the values I get out are still constrained to integers.

Why is this happening? How can I get higher precision color values?

Answer (score 2):

The rendered video images contained in a Canvas are constrained to the precision that the computer's graphics card is using, which is almost always 8 bits per channel these days.  If you want more precision than this, you'll need to perform the interpolation yourself off-screen.

Comment: I see! So I need to get the pixel values, apply the blur then the maths I want, all without using a canvas..
Do you know of any good starter examples of off-screen video maths like this? Thanks!